# how can I Set username and password in SOAP request using apache cxf artifacts

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I am new to webservices concept. I have generated java artifacts with WSDL provided, using Apache cxf tool in SOAPUI. But i am not sure how to set the username and password which are there in header of the SOAP request. i can see there is a classs AuthenticationInfo created with all the parameters like username and password.

please let me know how can i call that class or pass the values of username and password to the header part of the SOAP request. if I run the package with out setting these details i am getting Authentication failed error.

Please help me.

Thanks,
hari

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about passing username/password in the SOAP header as per [UsernameToken profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf) described in [WS-Security specification](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16790/wss-v1.1-spec-os-SOAPMessageSecurity.pdf) , CXF let's you do that using `WSS4J Interceptors`.

Take a look at following :

1. [CXF - WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)
2. [WSS4J Project](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/)

In your client you will need to add the WSS4JOutInterceptor.